# loop that will generate math problems until told to stop

Tags: python, loops, math, random

I am learning how to use random and math functions but I never really understood loops. so lets say I need a loop that will ask random math problems until told to stop. For something simple like addition of numbers from 0 to 9 how do I write a loop that keeps generating problems. 
this is an example of a how it can look like:

```
Math()
Are you ready? yes 
0 + 5 = 5
4 + 9 = 13
3 + 2 = 89
7 + 7 = 14 
5 + 4 = 9
1 + 8 = stop
```

so far I have this but I don't know how to make a loop:

```
def Math():
    ready=input('Are you ready?')
    num1 = int(random.randint(0,10))
    num2 = int(random.randint(0,10))
    if ready = 'yes':
        while result != 'stop':
            num1+'+'+num2 = result
```

I honestly have no idea how to make a while loop. please help me. 
Thank you

Comment: Where does `result` come from... you need `==` in `ready = 'yes'`

Comment: As a general approach to loops: 1. start with a `while True` loop; 2. figure out which code needs to be before the loop, repeated in the loop, or after the loop; 3. add (conditional) breaks to the loop body; 4. see if the loop can be refactored to be a for loop, to use the break condition (or in some languages, to become a do-while loop)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you wanna:
1. print 'num1 + num2 = '
2. get the `result` from keyboard
3. loop until the `result` is 'stop'

```
def Math():
    ready = raw_input('Are you ready?')
    if ready != 'yes':
        return
    while True:
        num1 = int(random.randint(0,10))
        num2 = int(random.randint(0,10))
        result = raw_input('%d + %d = ')
        if result == 'stop':
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing several things.

- You need to check `ready == 'yes'`, not assign `ready = 'yes'`.
- You also need to generate new numbers `num1` and `num2` inside the loop, so you get new numbers every time.
- You also need to ask for the user's answer inside the loop, every time.  Right now `result` is coming from nowhere in your code.
- You do not need to cast the result of `random.randint` to an `int`, it already is an `int`, hence the name `randint`.

---

```
import random

def Math():
    if raw_input('Are you ready? ') != 'yes':
        return
    while True:
        num1 = random.randint(0,10)
        num2 = random.randint(0,10)
        result = raw_input('%d + %d = ' % (num1, num2))
        if result == 'stop':
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Math()
```